# FPDF for creating pdf diplomas

Tags: plugins, functions, oop, include, pdf

Before anything else, I must say I am new on building WordPress functions. I have a website with online courses. Students have to sit exams and at the end they get a score, an average of all the exams. I am trying to build a simple dynamic PDF diploma with their name and average score, no more, which I will download by clicking on a button from a table/list. I found the class [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), unzipped it and uploaded it through FTP. Then, I made an `include( 'fpdf183/fpdf.php');` on my *functions.php* in order to retrieve the *class FPDF*. After that, I went to my *student-page.php* and wrote this code to create the PDF:

```
 $sql ="SELECT DISTINCT(ID),`user_registered`...()";
    
        $request = $wpdb->get_results($sql); ?>
        <table id="example" class="display cell-border compact stripe" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Average score</th>
                <th>Download Diploma</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
    
      foreach ($request as $value) {

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        if( isset($_POST['generate_pdf'])){
    
          global $pdf;
          $title_line_height = 10;
          $content_line_height = 8;        
    
          $pdf->AddPage();
          $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 42 );
          $pdf->Write(20, 'This is a sample');
          $pdf->Write(20, $value->name);
          $pdf->Write(20, $value->average);
          $pdf->Output('D','sample.pdf');
         }
         <tr>
          <td><?php echo $value->name ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value->average ?></td>
          <td>
            <form method="post" id="as-fdpf-form">
              <button class="button button-primary" type="submit" name="generate_pdf" value="generate">Download</button>
            </form>
          </td>
         </tr>

        </tbody>
       </table>
```

I didn't copy the whole code, just the most important so that you get the idea. I do not know what I am doing wrong (maybe everything), but I would appreciate your help. :)

Comment: You can't output the PDF in the middle of a HTML page, you can output the PDF, or you can output a HTML page, but not both at the same time

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to do it outside HTML by creating a test.php page and putting inside just the code, it didn't work. But when I do it locally using WAMP it works perfectly. It just doesn't work with WordPress. Any suggestion? :)

Comment: You shouldn't make direct requests to PHP files in a plugin or theme, that's very bad practice and not the solution.